# Javascript HasOwnProperty Polyfill

Tags: javascript, polyfills, hasownproperty

I know this may sound like an absurd, unnecessary question, but it really isn't.

https://caniuse.com/?search=Hasownproperty shows 100% of tracked desktop clients support, which is as you would expect. But switching to tracked mobile clients shows a shocking mere 95.4% support, which given that mobile clients are even with or even outstripping desktop ones, means an extrapolation of around 2.5% of all *current* clients visiting a webpage DON'T support `hasOwnProperty` natively.

Given that a large amount of third-party libraries including jQuery, Modernizr, and Crockford’s json2.js reference `hasOwnProperty` and do not polyfill it, it's really quite important to polyfill this.

I am looking for a way to polyfill `hasOwnProperty` according to the spec. It can be shallowly polyfilled (albeit incorrectly) using a `for in` loop, but that won't return `false` for inherited properties.

Comment: So you want to code for bowsers with like 0% market share. :) I think Resig had on back from ages ago `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: Then you probably should also polyfill [==](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_equality), [=](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_assignment) (assignment) and some others. They have similar support ratios. Tbh I don't think it is relevant

Comment: Its not 0 bro, it's literally ~2.5% right now, according to CanIUse.

Comment: Lol oh man, I draw the line at JS syntax itself. There must be more to that number. I would assume that if it doesn't support =, ==, etc, then it doesn't support JS at all, like some ancient Nokia phone or something. Would be interested to confirm that theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check polyfill section of [object.hasOwnProperty](https://docs.w3cub.com/javascript/global_objects/object/hasownproperty/)

This is the implementation

```
(function(w){
var isFunction=w.isFunction||(w.isFunction=function(x){return typeof(x)==='function'}),
has=w.has||(w.has=function(o,p){var e=p in o;return {value:e && (e=o[p]) && true,refer:e,valueOf:function(){return this.value}}}),
Polyfill=w.PolyfillMethod||(w.PolyfillMethod=function(o,p,x){var e=has(o,p);if(e && (e=isFunction(e.refer))===false){o[p]=x};return e}),
theProto=w.Object.prototype;

Polyfill(theProto,'hasOwnProperty',function(x){var o,e=this,p=String(x);return p in e && (o=e.__proto__||e.constructor.prototype,(p in o ===false)||e[p]!== o[p])});

})(window);
```